# Placing custom execution rate limits on AWS Step Functions

Tags: throttling, aws-step-functions

I have a Step functions setup that is spawning a Lambda function. The Lambda functions are getting spawned too fast and causing other services to throttle, so I would like Step functions to have a rate limit on the number of job it kicks off at a given time.

How do I best approach this?

Comment: I need this too? Was there an approach you took? Lambda solution doesn't apply for me.

Comment: @Snickers3192 Only if you use Activities, then you can make the host executing the activities limit to a single execution at a time and custom set interval restrictions. With Lambda, there was no good solution I could find.

Comment: That's not what I want to hear lol I need this for my job! haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try setting this limit at Lambda Function side using concurrent execution limit - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/concurrent-executions.html. This way you can limit maximum number of executions of that specific Lambda Function thus leaving unreserved concurrency pool for rest of functions.